# Python - how to ignore escape chars in regexp

Tags: regex, python-2.7

My goal is to identify this pattern:

```
STR("<some_string>")
```

I've build this regexp:

```
(STR\()"(.+?)("\))
```

This works fine on most cases, However fails on this example:

```
STR("test \") string")
```

In the above case I wish to get `test \") string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
(STR\()"(.+?)(?<!\\)("\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wS5iC5/1)

Example:

```
>>> s1 = r'STR("<some_string>")'
>>> s2 = r'STR("test \") string")'
>>> re.findall(r'STR\("(.+?)(?<!\\)"\)', s1)
['<some_string>']
>>> re.findall(r'STR\("(.+?)(?<!\\)"\)', s2)
['test \\") string']
```

`(?<!\\)"` Negative lookbehind assertion based pattern would asserts that the double quotes won't be preceded by a backslash character.

**OR**

```
STR\("((?:\\"|[^"])*)"\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wS5iC5/2)

Comment: I have false negative in this phrase  `STR("a\\b\\c\\")` In this case `\\"` should be matches since we escape the char \ and not the char "